# Recursion in Egg Drop Puzzle

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic

There are n number of eggs and building which has k floors. Write an algorithm to find the minimum number of drops is required to know the floor from which if egg is dropped, it will break.

My Solution was to break the floors into group of blocks of size sqrt(k). For example, if k =100, i will be checking if the egg will break from floor 10, 20, 30....100 and then linear search in that block. The solution will be O(sqrt(k)).

Now, the Dynamic Programming Solution I am seeing is :

```
When we drop an egg from a floor x, there can be two cases (1) The egg breaks (2) The egg doesn’t break.

1) If the egg breaks after dropping from xth floor, then we only need to check for floors lower than x with remaining eggs; so the problem reduces to x-1 floors and n-1 eggs
2) If the egg doesn’t break after dropping from the xth floor, then we only need to check for floors higher than x; so the problem reduces to k-x floors and n eggs.

Since we need to minimize the number of trials in worst case, we take the maximum of two cases. We consider the max of above two cases for every floor and choose the floor which yields minimum number of trials. 
     k ==> Number of floors
     n ==> Number of Eggs
      eggDrop(n, k) ==> Minimum number of trials needed to find the critical
                        floor in worst case.
      eggDrop(n, k) = 1 + min{max(eggDrop(n - 1, x - 1), eggDrop(n, k - x)): 
                     x is floors in {1, 2, ..., k}}
```

I havent why are we using `eggDrop(n, k - x)` to compute for `Floor above x with k-x` as it will give **k floors below x** and **not floors above X exactly** ?
For Example, on x = 6
`eggDrop(10, 2) = 1 + min{max(eggDrop(2 - 1, 6 - 1), eggDrop(2, 9 - 6))`
Gives,
`eggDrop(10, 2) = 1 + min{max(eggDrop(1, 5), eggDrop(2, 3))`
**eggDrop(2, 3))** is basically a building with 3 floor and 2 eggs and not floors above 6th Floor.

Thanks!

Source : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-11-egg-dropping-puzzle/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=egg+drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what those floors are. What matters is **the number of floors we need to consider**. If we have 9 floors and an egg survives the 6th floor, we need to consider the 3 floors above 6: the 7th, 8th, and 9th floor. Another way to think about it is that having to test the floors 7-9 is exactly the same as testing the floors 1-3 (in terms of the number of drops in the worst case).

Comment: @Kartik I don't mean the actual results of the test. If you already know that the desired floor will be from 7 to 9, it's essentially the same problem as if you know the egg will break in floors 1 to 3. Remember that we only care about the worst case scenario here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how many floors are above the 6th floor? That would be 3 (floors 7, 8, 9). It doesn't matter how high up these floors are if you're trying to figure out which is the culprit.

Let me draw you a different example for reference. Let's say you're trying to do a binary search through a sorted list just to see if an element exists.

Example list: `values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Let's say that you're searching for 3. The first step would be to look at the middle element, `v[2]` and compare it with 3. Since 3 is greater than `v[2] = 2`, you should recursively call `binarySearch(a1)` on the subarray `v[3 - 4]`.

What happens in the recursive call? At this point, it is basically a base case, so it might look at `a1[0] = 3`. The comparison works, so you return `TRUE`.

In this example, calling `binarySearch` on the subarray `v[3 - 4]` is the same as calling `eggDrop(2, 3)`. When you reference `a1[0]`, you're really referencing `v[3]`. Similarly, floor 1 in the recursive call to `eggDrop` is really referencing floor 7 in the parent call. The indices "reset", but they really refer to the same value.